# How to catch cancallation of UIScrollView or others?

Tags: iphone, events, ipad, ios, interruption

Sometimes, interruptions such as phone call occur and disturb a regular behavior of an app in iPhone or iPad.

For example, I created one UIScrollView instance and implemented UIScrollView delegate methods: scrollViewWillBeginDragging and scrollViewDidEndDragging(and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating).

A scrollViewWillBeginDragging method deactivated all custom buttons in my app. 
Then scrollViewDidEndDragging and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating methods activated these custom buttons. That is, while the user scrolled, all custom buttons became deactivated for a while.

> The problem was that while the user
>   started to drag and just held an
>   UIScrollView instance, if I took a
>   screenshot by pressing a home button
>   and a power button, then any of
>   scrollViewDidEndDragging and
>   scrollViewDidEndDecelerating didn't
>   get called. So the app became messed
>   up.

I implemented a UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification method in my UIViewController, but it didn't get called after taking a screenshot.

**How can I catch any kind of interruption that disturbs a regular flow of events?**

Sometimes, touchesEnd and touchesCanceled didn't get called too due to an interruption.

Thank you.

Comment: How about implementing viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear and testing if they get called after taking a screenshot? Then in those methods if (beingDragged == TRUE) call your scrollViewDidEndDragging method.

Comment: viewDidScroll method also gets called even in interruptions? probably not and there you have an alternative approach to you problem.

Comment: I'm new to things, so I'm not sure why you'd disable a button when the user was using a different view? The impression I have from various readings is that the only time you'd want to disable a button is when it can't actually perform it's function because some bit of data is missing, i.e. no selection, or a field not filled in, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and got rid of it by using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` method of NSObject.

In scrollViewDidScroll:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:yourController];
[yourController deactivateButtons];
[yourController performSelector:@selector(activateButtons) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

You can try this technique and combine it with other that you mentioned. 
Hope, that will help. Good luck!